# Problem with figure caption in responsive image gallery using HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm currently making a (static) website from scratch (so code the HTML and CSS stuff myself), and I want to have a responsive "image gallery" that changes the width of the pictures according to your screen width, so I followed this tutorial: [CSS Image Gallery - responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive)

However, changing it to my own likings I encountered an issue I could not fix with my current HTML/CSS skillset (it is not that much, I'm quite new in this). My problem is when I have (in my example three) images of the same size in my gallery, but the captions of the image have different length, this negatively affects the text that is followed by the gallery (see example and image below). I tried to fix this with the tutorials available at W3 and stuff, but nothing worked yet.

**Does any of you how to (easily) fix this?** And if so, please explain what you changed, because I want to truly understand what is going on at my website (that is why I didn't want to use these static site generators).

*Note: I have made 3 types of galleries, one for two, three and four images, which explains the ".responsivethree" etc classes*

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-NL">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size:11pt;
}

header {
    max-width: 800px;
}

main {
    max-width: 800px;
}

section {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

footer {
    max-width: 800px;
}


div.gallery {
  padding: 0px;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 85%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsivefour {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

.responsivethree {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.32%;
}

.responsivetwo {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 49.9988%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsivefour {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsivefour {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsivethree {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsivetwo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
<header  id="top">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
<main>
<article id="test">
    <h2>bla</h2>
    <section>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiamlobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetrasollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, adignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestieut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper. 
        </p>
        <div class="responsivethree">
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image 1">
          <div class="desc">--- short description ---</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsivethree">
            <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image 2" >
              <div class="desc">--- Very, utterly, super uber mega long description, don't you think, geeeeeez! ---</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsivethree">
            <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image 3" >
              <div class="desc">--- stuff ---</div>
            </div>
      </div>
        <p>
            <b>This is my problem...</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiamlobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetrasollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, adignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestieut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
        </p>
    </section>
</article>
</main>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
<footer>
    <p style="text-align: center;">footer tooter</p>
</footer>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float:left property you gave to the responsivethree class aligns the images to the left. Since you did not reset the left justification feature afterward, you are having a problem with the text scrolling. The clear:both command is used to reset the float:left property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-NL">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size:11pt;
}

header {
    max-width: 800px;
}

main {
    max-width: 800px;
}

section {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

footer {
    max-width: 800px;
}


div.gallery {
  padding: 0px;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 85%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsivefour {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

.responsivethree {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.32%;
}

.responsivetwo {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 49.9988%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsivefour {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsivefour {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsivethree {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .responsivetwo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
<header  id="top">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
<main>
<article id="test">
    <h2>bla</h2>
    <section>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiamlobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetrasollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, adignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestieut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper. 
        </p>
        <div class="responsivethree">
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image 1">
          <div class="desc">--- short description ---</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsivethree">
            <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image 2" >
              <div class="desc">--- Very, utterly, super uber mega long description, don't you think, geeeeeez! ---</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsivethree">
            <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image 3" >
              <div class="desc">--- stuff ---</div>
            </div>
      </div>
        <p class="clear">
            <b>This is my problem...</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiamlobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetrasollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, adignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestieut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
        </p>
    </section>
</article>
</main>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
<footer>
    <p style="text-align: center;">footer tooter</p>
</footer>
<!-- #################################################################### -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, due to your comment I actually saw that I miscopied the example by W3. They already made a `clear:both` command, I just forgot to put the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the gallery. Thanks for the explanation (this made that I understand it now :) )